# Is in babel [canadian]=[USenglish]?

Tags: babel, languages

I'm currently writing a letter to canada and therefore use `\usepackage[canadian]{babel}`. But would it be the same to use `[USenglish]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in `english.ldf` you find

```
\ifx\l@canadian\@undefined
  \adddialect\l@canadian\l@american
\fi
```

that is, Canadian is considered as a “dialect” of US English. This is also proved by the simple document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[canadian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\the\language
\end{document}
```

that prints

> 0

which is the number assigned to US English (for compatibility reasons, this is always the default language).

Answer (score 1):

The user guide in the babel-english folder starts off with

> The file english.dtx defines all the language definition macros for the English
>   language as well as for the American and Australian version of this language. For
>   the Australian version the British hyphenation patterns will be used, if available,
>   for the Canadian variant the American patterns are selected.

and also

> 'Canadian' english spelling is a hybrid of British and American spelling. Although so far no special 'translations' have been reported we allow this file to be loaded by the option 'canadian' as well.

The file `english.dtx` features the instructions

```
...
%%% (The following condition will be executed only if "l@english" isn't 
%%% defined, which shouldn't really happen unless something went wrong
%%% during the installation of babel.)
\ifx\l@canadian\@undefined
  \let\l@english\l@canadian
\fi
```

and, later,

```
\ifx\l@canadian\@undefined
  \adddialect\l@canadian\l@american
\fi
```

At least for the time being, the Canadian English patterns for hyphenation, etc are the same as for (US) American English.

Comment: That's the other way around and that assignment is actually never performed because it's in a conditional subject to `\ifx\l@english\@undefined` (which is false under normal circumstances).

Comment: @egreg -- I've provided a longer excerpt from `english.dtx`. It turns out that if the `canadian` language option is set, `\l@english` is first let to `\l@canadian` and then the `\l@canadian` "dialect" is set to `\l@american`.

Comment: No, the assignment `\let\l@english\l@canadian` is never performed unless `\l@english` has been undefined before `english.ldf` is loaded. That initial code in `english.ldf` is just for taking care of strange installations.

Comment: @egreg - So, is the documentation wrong (or misleading)?

Comment: The documentation says that for Canadian, the US English hyphenation patterns are used and it is correct. To the contrary your explanation why this happens was wrong. Now it is *almost* correct (the first conditional is never executed), and the same as mine.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. I hadn't picked up on the fact that the first conditional will (almost certainly) never be executed (i.e., not unless something weird happened in the installation of `babel`.